# Not getting Text notification from one contact

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 8 and I just started having a problem where I don’t get a text notification or anything from one specific contact, no blue dot beside the convo or anything. I do not have do not disturb on I have reset all settings and I have done everything that I could. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Are you expecting the cell phone company to send the notification or an app? Is this SMS / iMessage or some other text?

Comment: This is on iMessage and it’s just a regular conversation

Comment: So they send you an iCloud message from an email to your device, and you see the message and don’t get what precisely? What do you consider a notification? Sound / vibration / lock screen alert?

Comment: This is from iMessage text not email when the person text me I don’t get a pop up notification sound or vibration I have check to see I’d do not disturb is on and it is not

Comment: is that person using your email address or your phone number to send the text message?  Did the person say if the message was returned or if a message saying it couldn't be delivered was given.